# Google API Client Library for Julia?

Tags: google-people-api

Would it be possible to have Google API Client Library for Julia? Roadmap? Any alternatives?

PyCall is an alternative for now. It would be great that Julia can be supported natively.

JuliaPy/PyCall.jl: Package to call Python functions from the Julia language
https://github.com/JuliaPy/PyCall.jl

Comment: I second that, would be great to have something native in Julia